# Classe SmsManager saber se enviou mesmo o sms

Tags: android, sms

Uso a classe SmsManager para enviar sms no meu aplicativo assim

```
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage (telefones.get(i), null, smsManager.divideMessage(men), enviados, entregues);
```

ai tem esta parte do codigo aqui que retorna se conseguil enviar ou não

```
context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode())
        {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                j++;
                Toast.makeText(context, j + " SMSs enviados", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Falha Geral", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sem serviço", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Radio desligado", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

}, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

tava querendo passar os telefones juntos com o intent enviados , alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Não tem como, pra isso, o destinatário deveria enviar uma resposta, e isso não acontece.

Comment: tem como sim porque eu achei aqui mesmo no forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137836/trouble-with-sendmultiparttext-in-android , só que não entendi muito bem como e

Comment: Cara esta falando bobagem, esse link q mandou não tem nada a ver com sua pergunta

Comment: me mandaram falando que tinha a ver culpa e minha não

Comment: mais quando envia sms normal pelo celular , quando o sms chega no celular da pessoa você recebe uma notificação

Comment: Ilgner, mesmo que a "culpa" não seja sua, você é responsável por toda informação que coloca aqui. Esse tipo de atitude não ajuda a obter respostas, ok?

Comment: Outra coisa: a confirmação é possível, em pelo menos alguns casos. Há uma pergunta no SO sobre isso, respondida: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639778/how-to-monitor-each-of-sent-sms-status/4640066

Comment: @Renan o conteúdo link que você mandou e o mesmo do link que eu mandei e o Antony falou que eu estava falando bobagem :/

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira isso mostra duas coisas: 1-) você não leu o que está nos links, pois são duas perguntas completamente diferentes e 2-) ou o Antony ainda não viu a pergunta e a resposta no link que eu mandei, ou ele já testou a solução que lá consta (mesmo sem ter visto a resposta) e chegou a conclusão de que não funciona. Você ao menos tentou seguir o que diz [esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4640066/2263584)?

Comment: eu sei que são duas perguntas diferentes , mais la fala sobre pegar este tipo de retorno , eu tentei mais deu um erro la falando que registerReceiver não existe